# Hi when closing bootstrap modal I am take to the top of page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3.3, when I am closing bootstrap modal it is taking me to the top of the page.

Code of close button is : ×

I want the remain in location as I was before opening modal. But closing modal is taking me to top of the page

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.